# How to display the content of a specific button after one of three buttons is clicked? All buttons should be hidden after one of them was clicked

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, material-ui, conditional-statements, conditional-rendering

Goal: I should display the specific contents of a specific button after one of three buttons was clicked. Then, after the specific button is clicked, all three buttons should be hidden and replaced with the contents of the clicked specific button.

Issue: I tried passing props and using if-else statement in terms of conditional rendering but I am having trouble figuring out how to properly state a condition for the functionality to work since the remaining if else statements are ignored. Only the Beef button is working but the rest of the buttons are not.

Source code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Stack } from '@mui/material';
import FoodTraysItemButton from "./FoodTraysItemButton";
import PastaNoodlesButtonsFT from "./foodTraysPages/PastaNoodlesButtonsFT";
import DessertsButtonsFT from "./foodTraysPages/DessertsButtonsFT";
import BeefButtonsFT from "./foodTraysPages/BeefButtonsFT";
import { useState } from "react";

function preventDefault(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

export default function FoodTraysButtons(props) {
  const [myBoolBeef, setmyBoolBeef] = useState(true);
  const [myBoolDesserts, setmyBoolDesserts] = useState(true);
  const [myBoolPastaNoodles, setmyBoolPastaNoodles] = useState(true);
  
   function toggleBoolBeef() {
     setmyBoolBeef(!myBoolBeef);
   }

    function toggleBoolDesserts() {
      setmyBoolDesserts(!myBoolDesserts);
    } 

    function toggleBoolPastaNoodles() {
      setmyBoolPastaNoodles(!myBoolPastaNoodles);
    }

  return (
    // stuck here:   (I plan to use multiple separate if else statements to work the functionality out but it doesn't work)
    <React.Fragment> 
     {(() => {
         // only works here
        if (myBoolBeef) {
          return (<Landing toggleBoolBeef={toggleBoolBeef} />);
        } else{
          return <BeefFT/>;
        }
      
// these are ignored:
        if (myBoolDesserts) {
          return (<Landing toggleBoolDesserts={toggleBoolDesserts} />);
        } else{
          return <DessertsFT/>;
        } 

        if (myBoolPastaNoodles) {
          return (<Landing toggleBoolPastaNoodles={toggleBoolPastaNoodles} />);
        } else{
          return <PastaNoodlesFT/>;
        } 


      })()}
    </React.Fragment>
  );

}

function Landing(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Stack spacing={0} direction="row" sx={{ mb: 4.5 }}>
        <FoodTraysItemButton
          title="Beef"
          onClick={props.toggleBoolBeef}
        />
      
        <FoodTraysItemButton
          title="Desserts"
          onClick={props.toggleBoolDesserts}
        />
        <FoodTraysItemButton title="Pasta/Noodles" onClick={props.toggleBoolPastaNoodles} />
      
      </Stack>
     

    </div>
  );
}

function BeefFT() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BeefButtonsFT />
    </div>
  );
}


function DessertsFT() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DessertsButtonsFT />
    </div>
  );
}

function PastaNoodlesFT() {
  return (
    <div>
      <PastaNoodlesButtonsFT />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Full source codes in Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/show-hide-buttons-ralph-ecv9g2?file=/src/FoodTraysButtons.jsx:773-815

How it should look like:

Beef button:
[image: beefff]

[image: beef]

Desserts button:
[image: deessers]

[image: desserts]

Pasta Noodles button:
[image: pasta]

[image: pastaaaa]

In what way should I implement this in order to achieve its functionality?

Your responses would be highly appreciated as I am exploring MUI and React at the moment. It would be a really big help for my project. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `FoodTraysButtons` to hold a single state, `selection` that is then used to conditionally render the `Landing` component or any of `BeefFT`, `DessertsFT`, or `PastaNoodlesFT` component.

```
export default function FoodTraysButtons(props) {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState();

  const selectHandler = (selection) => setSelection(selection);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {!selection && <Landing onSelect={selectHandler} />}
      {selection === "beef" && <BeefFT />}
      {selection === "dessets" && <DessertsFT />}
      {selection === "pastaNoodles" && <PastaNoodlesFT />}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Update the `Landing` component to take a single `onSelect` prop callback.

```
function Landing({ onSelect }) {
  const selectHandler = (selection) => () => onSelect(selection);
  return (
    <div>
      <Stack spacing={0} direction="row" sx={{ mb: 4.5 }}>
        <FoodTraysItemButton title="Beef" onClick={selectHandler("beef")} />
        <FoodTraysItemButton
          title="Desserts"
          onClick={selectHandler("desserts")}
        />
        <FoodTraysItemButton
          title="Pasta/Noodles"
          onClick={selectHandler("pastaNoodles")}
        />
      </Stack>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-display-the-content-of-a-specific-button-after-one-of-three-buttons-is-cl]

Comment: Oh I see, I should have used only one useState to be utilized by the whole system. I also did not have a selection handler since I was really baffled. Thus, your code tweaks definitely worked on my end!!! All clear and concise! Thank you very much for this @DrewReese

Answer (score 1):

You need a switch case block instead of multiple boolean value state. Consider this way of structuring your code:

```
const menuState = {
  NONE: "none",
  BEEF: "beef",
  DESSERTS: "desserts",
  PASTA: "pasta"
};

export default function FoodTraysButtons(props) {
  const [selectedMenu, setSelectedMenu] = useState(menuState.NONE);

  const renderMenu = () => {
    switch (selectedMenu) {
      case menuState.BEEF:
        return <BeefFT />;
      case menuState.DESSERTS:
        return <DessertsFT />;
      case menuState.PASTA:
        return <PastaNoodlesFT />;
      case menuState.NONE:
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {selectedMenu === menuState.NONE && (
        <Landing setSelectedMenu={setSelectedMenu} />
      )}
      {renderMenu()}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Landing(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Stack spacing={0} direction="row" sx={{ mb: 4.5 }}>
        <FoodTraysItemButton
          title="Beef"
          onClick={() => props.setSelectedMenu(menuState.BEEF)}
        />

        <FoodTraysItemButton
          title="Desserts"
          onClick={() => props.setSelectedMenu(menuState.DESSERTS)}
        />
        <FoodTraysItemButton
          title="Pasta/Noodles"
          onClick={() => props.setSelectedMenu(menuState.PASTA)}
        />
      </Stack>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working Demo:

[image: Edit show-hide-buttons-ralph (forked)]

NOTE: If you want to always show the button menu then remove the `selectedMenu === menuState.NONE` wrapper condition.

Comment: Move `<Landing setSelectedMenu={setSelectedMenu} />` into the `switch` as well and just call `renderMenu`.

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah, that will work too

Comment: Oh nice, I was literally thinking of using switch case method but I have no idea also if it will worked, but indeed it can. I consider this also a working method! Thank you very much for this @AmilaSenadheera